# Zend paginator with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework, pagination

I have multiple albums listed on a page, next to each album are listed reviews about the album. Essentially this means there are many reviews about many albums on a single page.

What would be the best approach to paginate each review section for each album? For example so each album displays only 3 reviews at a time, with a paginator to advance through the rest of the reviews for the album *without* leaving the album listing page, and also still listing the other albums and reviews associated with the albums.

Could this be achieved through the use of [Zend\Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html) and AJAX?

(I'm not necessarily looking for the perfect code because that would be impossible - just looking for the best way to approach the problem)

Thanks

**EDIT**

For reference: One possible solution may be to include a link in the view which fires a new action in the view controller to advance the page of the pagination. The action returns a JsonModel of the desired content to be paginated.

Open to any better approaches, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how your front-end is built but you are on the right track. Zend1 provided a nice helper called a [context switch](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch) that does most of the work for you (disables view, sets appropriate headers) but it's not necessary to use it. The general idea is to keep that functionality inside one action but display different content depending on "who's asking".

So, for example:

- /albums/show/id/1/ - would show an html page with album id=1 with reviews
- /albums/show/id/1/reviews/2 - would show an html page with album id=1 and reviews on that page would start at page 2
- /albums/show/id/1/reviews/2/context/ajax - outputs JSON of reviews from page 2 for an album with id=1

The benefit is that now you can have a fallback link without JavaScript to page 2 of reviews - and your code is much easier to understand too.

I hope this helps!